# not recieving email from my php form

Tags: php, forms

i have a html form and a php handler, but i am not recieving the emails that the form should be sending. I have searched around for hours and i cant figure it out. I have just started using php so help is greatly appreciated, thank you. heres my code. i have changed the email addresses for security reasons.

```
<form action="formHandler.php" method="post">
      <div class="forForm first">
      <label for="namename" class="contactLabel">Name</label><br /><input placeholder="Name" class="editable" type="text" name="namename" id="namename"/>
      </div>
      <div class="forForm second">
      <label for="emailemail" class="contactLabel">Email</label><br /><input placeholder="Email" class="editable" type="email" name="emailemail" id="emailemail" required/>
      </div>
      <div id="surname">
      <label for="surnamesurname" class="contactLabel">Surname</label><br /><input type="text" value="Smith" class="editable" name="surnamesurname" id="surnamesurname" />
      </div>
      <div>
      <input id="submitBTN" type="submit"/>
      </div>
      </form>
```

and formHandler.php

```
<?php    
$surname = $_REQUEST['surnamesurname'];
    if($surname != "Smith") {
    echo "We encountered a problem, please try again later1.";
    }else{
    $myemail = 'email@email.com';
    $name = $_REQUEST['namename'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['emailemail'];
    $from = "oneandone.net";
    $to = "contactform@domain.co.uk";
    $subject = "New sign up!";
    $body = "Someone new has signed up: \n Name: $name \n Email: $email";
    $headers = "From: $from";
    $result = "mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)";
    if(!$result){echo "your message was not sent";}
}
?>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not sending an email, you're defining a string

change

```
$result = "mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)";
```

to

```
$result = mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
```

And you might have more luck!

Comment: thank you, this sorted the problem perfectly, ill make sure i dont make that mistake again

Comment: Easy mistake to make, glad it helped!